# Get value from 1 table that are also in another and that are not in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get only ads that have not been posted from a MySQL db.

I have 3 tables, ad_title, items and posted_ads

ad_title - title_id, title, item_id

items - item_id, ad_body, accounts

posted_ads - post_id, title_id, item_id, account

I have been trying to get a list of ad_titles / items that have not been posted in a certain account without success. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  ad_title t
  JOIN items l 
   ON ( l.item_id= t.item_id
   AND l.accounts LIKE  '%myaccount@email.com%' ) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT q.item_id
  FROM posted_ads q
  WHERE q.acc_used =  'myaccount@email.com'
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - Thank you for your help, it works ! :) The only problem now is that ad_titles has more than 1 record per item and when the log logs a title in the db, it does not show the other ad_titles for that item. Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query's current form, you ought to be using `ad_title.items_id NOT IN (...)` with your subquery, since your `NOT EXISTS` subquery doesn't contain anything in the `WHERE` to relate it to the outer query

```
SELECT
  /* Don't actually SELECT * in a JOIN query. Be explicit about the needed columns */
  /* especially since you have item_id in all tables */
  t.*,
  l.* 
FROM 
  ad_title t
  JOIN items l 
   ON ( l.item_id= t.item_id
   AND l.accounts LIKE  '%myaccount@email.com%' ) 
WHERE
  /* Find item_id via NOT IN */ 
  t.item_id NOT IN (
    SELECT q.item_id
    FROM posted_ads q
    WHERE q.acc_used =  'myaccount@email.com'
  )
```

To make it work as a `NOT EXISTS`, you would need relate the subquery back to the outer query:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT q.item_id
  FROM posted_ads q
  WHERE 
    q.acc_used =  'myaccount@email.com'
    /* Need relation to the outer query */
    AND q.item_id = l.item_id
)
```

But this can also be done with a `LEFT JOIN`, looking for `NULL`s in `posted_ads`.  This may be the most efficient method:

```
SELECT
  /* Don't SELECT * in a JOIN query. Be explicit about the needed columns */
  t.*,
  l.* 
FROM 
  ad_title t
  JOIN items l 
   ON ( l.item_id= t.item_id
   AND l.accounts LIKE  '%myaccount@email.com%' ) 
  LEFT JOIN 
    posted_ads q 
      ON l.item_id = q.item_id
      AND q.acc_used = l.accounts
WHERE
  /* NULL in the posted_ads table means it doesn't exist there */ 
  posted_ads.item_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works ! :) The only problem now is that ad_titles has more than 1 record per item and when the log logs a title in the db, it does not show the other ad_titles for that item. Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: @user593893 Using which of the three versions above?

Comment: The first one. To clarify, one ad can have more than 1 title and i need to know which titles have been used in each account. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I meant I need to find out which titles have not been used with that account and get them as a result. First time posting here :)

Comment: @user593893 Try the `LEFT JOIN` version.  But also, please post a smal sample of data from all 3 tables.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your help. I made it work by changing the NOT IN and the subquery from item_id to title_id and that did the trick. Thank you very much.